# Acceptable to instantiate from an existing object?

Tags: php, oop

I discovered this by accident, and was wondering if this is expected behaviour:

```
Interactive shell

php > class dog {
php {   public $name='doggy';
php {   public function speak() {
php {     echo "bark, bark! (my name is " . $this->name . ")\n";
php {   }
php { }
php >
php > $puppy = new dog;
php > $puppy->speak();
bark, bark! (my name is doggy)
php >
php > $taffy = new $puppy;
php > $taffy->speak();
bark, bark! (my name is doggy)
php >
php > $taffy->name = "Taffy";
php > $taffy->speak();
bark, bark! (my name is Taffy)
php >
php > $puppy->speak();
bark, bark! (my name is doggy)
php >
```

My question is about the line, `$taffy = new $puppy;`

Normally, I would have coded `$taffy = new dog;`

I wouldn't have expected to be able to create a new object by instantiating from an instantiation... if that makes any sense.

Is this expected functionality, or just a happy accident?

---

I discovered this when building a model that needed to talk to several different db tables, and I use dependency injection to pass the database abstraction:

```
class ShowConnectedTables {
  public function __constructor($db) {
    $this->modelOne = new ModelOne($db);
    $this->modelTwo = new ModelTwo($db);
  }
  // ... snip ...
}

$table = new ShowConnectedTables(new Database);
```

Sometimes, though, a database call to ModelTwo in the middle of a loop fetching ModelOne's rows could clobber the fetching of ModelOne's rows.  So is it acceptable to

```
class ShowConnectedTables {
  public function __constructor($db) {
    $this->modelOne = new ModelOne($db);
    $this->modelTwo = new ModelTwo(new $db); // note new abstraction
  }
  // ... snip ...
}

$table = new ShowConnectedTables(new Database);
```

Comment: It's certainly more conventional to use `clone` - I don't think it's a particularly common situation to want to create a new object based on an existing one, rather than also wanting its state to be represented in the copy. I also had no idea this worked (and apparently has since PHP 5 first came out), so thanks for teaching me something.

Comment: see here: http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.basic.php#example-218 apparently this behaviour is not unconventional, from the example, @MarkBaker seems wrong, as the test show that objects created are different

Comment: @MarkBaker I think that's referring to doing `$newObj = $existingObj`, rather than `$newObj = *new* $existingObj`

Comment: Huh, I had no idea you could do that either. I wouldn't do it, simply because _it's weird_. If I came back to that code later, I probably wouldn't even realize what was going on at first.

Comment: yeah, wouldn't use it too unless forced to.. but that can be useful! The kind of things you put a comment in the code in case you forget

Comment: I stand corrected; something new for me

Comment: @Kaddath What's a _"comment"_? ;)

Comment: @Don'tPanic a comment in the code for documentation, with `//` or `/**/`. Sorry if that's not the proper term, english is not my native language

Comment: @Kaddath sorry, I was kidding. I shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Don'tPanic :D of course you should do that, life would be too boring unless! already so many askers don't know what are docs (are they a myth?).. i won't try and ask people to comment their code! definetly too much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen this or done this.  As a result, I would probably avoid it: if it is going to cause other developers to look at it and scratch their heads (just like you did), it probably isn't worth it.  I can't see any reason why you would specifically have to do this, after all.

Don't Panic has pointed out that, while not explicitly documented, there is an example of doing this in the PHP documentation.  [Example 5 on this page.](https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-176)

That being said, there is no cloning going on:

```
class dog {
    public $name='doggy';
    public function speak() {
        echo "bark, bark! (my name is " . $this->name . ")\n<br>";
    }
    public function __clone() {
        print 'This is not called!';
        parent::__clone();
    }
}
$class = 'dog';
$puppy = new dog;
$puppy->name = 'Puppy';
$taffy = new $puppy;
if ( spl_object_hash( $taffy ) != spl_object_hash( $puppy ) )
    print 'not the same object';
$taffy->speak();
```

If you do the above you will find that the objects are not the same and the __clone method is never called.  Also, your taffy will be initialized with the name of `doggy`, not `Puppy`.  It seems this is effectively shorthand for:

```
$class = get_class( $puppy );
$taffy = new $class;
```

Comment: It is documented, somewhat. [http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php](here), in example 5. There's not really any description of it, though.

Comment: Sure enough, there it is in the docs.  Easy to miss, though.  `get_class` was something I was about to try when I stumbled on this.  Thanks for the input; I'll let this sit for a day before accepting an answer.

Comment: updated link: https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-176

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of creating a new reference to existing object. The constructor is executed, so that means, this is a new object. I've tired it:

```
<?php

class dog {
   public $name;
   public function __construct($name = '') {
       $this->name = $name ?: 'doggy';
   }
   public function speak() {
     echo "bark, bark! (my name is " . $this->name . ")\n";
   }
}

$puppy = new dog;
$puppy->speak(); #bark, bark! (my name is doggy)

$taffy = new $puppy('Snuffels');
$taffy->speak(); #bark, bark! (my name is Snuffels)

$taffy->name = "Taffy";
$taffy->speak(); #bark, bark! (my name is Taffy)

$puppy->speak(); #bark, bark! (my name is doggy)
echo $puppy;
```

The reason IMO is, that you can already use things like `new self` or `new parent`, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

> In the class context, it is possible to create a new object by `new self` and `new parent`.

I assume, that they implement a class recognition from things after `new`. But still a good WTF :)