# How do new Keyword works beside an object variable in PHP?

Tags: php, class, keyword

While studying OOP in PHP, I noticed [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) in `Example #5 Creating new objects` that the 'new' keyword used beside an object variable created a new object.
Let me mention an example here:

```
    Class Test {
          function getInstance(){
           return new $this;
          }
   }

$Object1 = new Test();
$Object2 = $Object1->getInstance(); // this will create new object from the same class
```

Another Example :

```
Class Test2{

}

$Object3 = new Test2();
$Object4 = new $Object3();// this will also create new object from the same class
```

**[The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new)** didn't mention any declaration upon this and I didn't find any further references clarifying the issue.

How does this work, although the documentation for using the 'new' keyword states the below mentioned rules:

> If a string containing the name of a class is used with new, a new instance of that class will be created. If the class is in a namespace, its fully qualified name must be used when doing this.

Comment: There's some discussion about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45885608/acceptable-to-instantiate-from-an-existing-object

Comment: @iainn : thanks for the provided link , extremely helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why and how the new keyword is being used with the already existing object of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334736/why-and-how-the-new-keyword-is-being-used-with-the-already-existing-object-of-a)

Answer (score -1):

It is referenced in the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for "example #5", where it describes that `PHP 5.3.0 introduced a couple of new ways to create instances of an object`

My answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334736/why-and-how-the-new-keyword-is-being-used-with-the-already-existing-object-of-a/47335209#47335209) explains the differences between `new class()`, `new $class()` and `clone $class` in much more detail

Comment: Although in classic PHP Documentation style, this has actually worked since PHP 5: https://3v4l.org/XtKLd

Comment: strange behavior.